# Pass form validation errors back to Wagtail Page template

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views, wagtail

I have a Wagtail Page model that I am using to render a form. I have overridden the `get_context` and `serve` methods to pass in the form as page context and then validate it when receiving a `POST` request:

```py
class RegistrationPage(Page):
    ...

    def get_context(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Avoid circular dependency
        from registration.forms import RegistrationForm

        context = super().get_context(request)

        context["form"] = RegistrationForm

        return context

    def serve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Avoid circular dependency
        from registration.forms import RegistrationForm

        if request.method == "POST":
            registration_form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)

            if registration_form.is_valid():
                registration = registration_form.save()

                return redirect("/")
            else:
                # How do I pass the form with validation errors to the page?
                # Note: I already have template logic to render the form errors
                # I just need to pass the invalidated form to the template
        else:
            return super().serve(request)
```

**Question:**

When the form validation fails, how do I pass the form back to the template so the user can see the validation errors?

Answer (score 0):

The answer I found was to attach the form to the Page model inside an `__init__` method and then override the form with the invalidated form inside of the `serve` method:

```py
class RegistrationPage(Page):
    ...

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Avoid circular dependency
        from registration.forms import RegistrationForm

        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.registration_form = RegistrationForm

    def get_context(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        context = super().get_context(request)

        context["form"] = self.registration_form

        return context

    def serve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Check if form was submitted
        if request.method == "POST":
            registration_form = self.registration_form(request.POST)

            if registration_form.is_valid():
                registration = registration_form.save()

                messages.success(request, 'Registration added successfully!')

                return redirect("/")
            else:
                self.registration_form = registration_form

        return super().serve(request)
```